# WebDav on Azure Blob storage

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

Is there a way to implement IT HIT WebDAV on the Azure blob file storage? We really don't want to buy Virtual Machine to do so, we already got Web  Application running on Azure and we want to store all Documents/Files on the Azure file storage. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously no one can answer this, desperately need to sort this out!

Comment: A workaround would be adding a VM with IIS - but that cannot be the solution.

Comment: We have done it with an Azure Function....for Azure FILES....

Comment: Anyone worked this out? @Alfred can you elaborate more on your approach?

Answer (score 5):

IT Hit has created a WebDAV Server sample with Azure Data Lake back-end and Azure Active Directory integration. The sample configuration description is located here: [ASP.NET Core WebDAV Server Sample with Azure Blob / Data Lake Storage Back-End](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/azure_blob_data_lake/). You can browse the source code of this sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/ITHit/WebDAVServerSamples/tree/master/CS/WebDAVServer.AzureDataLakeStorage.AspNetCore).

The document's content in this sample is indexed by Azure Cognitive Search. The detailed instructions for its configuration could be found here: [Azure Data Lake Full-Text Cognitive Search Configuration](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/azure_blob_data_lake/cognitive_search/):

You can also create and deploy this sample directly to your Azure account using the [ASP.NET WebDAV Server Data Lake Wizard](https://azure.webdavsystem.com/), which will really save you a lot of time.