# Integration of WebDav with azure blob storage

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

I need to use webdav in my application but i have one question which is related to azure blob storage support.

Is it possible to integrate azure blob storage with webdav?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467473/webdav-on-azure-blob-storage ?